# mapviz - transforming local xy coordinate frame to tile map lat/lon coordinate frame

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a tile map plugin for mapviz. As I move my mouse on the map I can see the GPS coordinates changing on the ui interface. I also used the swri_transform_util to give my robot a lat/lon xy origin. Now I am trying to use the point click publisher to get lat/lon coordinates when a place on the map is clicked. I am not sure what the tile map frame is however. I can get my robot's local xy position when I click on the map, but not sure how to transform it to the lat/lon coordinate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259785/mapviz---transforming-local-xy-coordinate-frame-to-tile-map-lat/lon-coordinate-frame/) by [obotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7461/obotic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I was looking in some of the other swri packages there is a function called Wgs84FromLocalXy in package swri_transform_util. It takes local xy, referenced lat/lon, and outputs the transform(no tf). So it looks like in my subscriber I can call this function. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but it seems to work for me right now.

---

Originally posted by [obotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7461/obotic/) with karma: 41 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-21**:
That is probably used because lat/long cannot be directly converted into metres in X and Y as used by tf, because they are angles referenced against a spheroid, not a perfect sphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Expressing_latitude_and_longitude_as_linear_units

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `view_frames` utility from `tf` to see what the frames are in your system. From that you should be able to make a good guess which is correct for the tile map frame.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [obotic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7461/obotic/) on 2017-04-21**:
Thanks Geoff, I forgot about that utility. I saw that there was no frame from the tile map which then made me realize maybe the transform is done another way.